# how to make 3 tiles in one row in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, adminlte

i want to show 3 tiles in a one row. 3 tiles should come in one row in the mobile view also.now im able to see only 3 tiles in one row but in mobile its showing two tiles in a row. how to make 3 tiles should cover complete row and same 3 tiles i need to show mobile also .im using adminlte theme for the design

code pen

https://codepen.io/krishnakernel/pen/VQQyaV

```
 <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <div class="small-box bg-green">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3>64 &#8451;<sup style="font-size: 20px"></sup></h3>
                        <p><span>Oil Temperature</span></p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-thermometer-3"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">
                        More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <div class="small-box bg-yellow">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3>88<span style="font-size:30px">Amp</span></h3>
                        <p>R Current </p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-flash"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href="" class="small-box-footer">
                        More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-6">
                <!-- small box -->
                <div class="small-box bg-red">
                    <div class="inner">
                        <h3>233 <span style="font-size:20px">&#9889;</span> </h3>
                        <p>R Voltage in kva</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="icon">
                        <i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>
                    </div>
                    <a href="#" class="small-box-footer">
                        More info <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></i>
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: the sum need to be 12, for example in lg, you need to change to 4, because you have 3 lg's

Comment: remove everything and keep only `col-xs-4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing the classes to `col-xs-4` for all the elements you want to have displayed in a row.

Comment: https://codepen.io/krishnakernel/pen/VQQyaV as u said i did but not working

Comment: You have unclosed tag at the end of the first item

Comment: what i have enclosed i didnt get. can u modify my codepen code

Comment: There is tag "</>" in your html code. You need to change it to "</div>" and it will work. It is right before the second element.

Answer (score 1):

You didnt close the div properly
[image]
 Change `<div class="col-lg-3 col-xs-4">`

Comment: its not working its showing 3 divs in 3 rows. i need 3 div in one row only

Comment: can u please tell how to reduce the gap between the divs.

Comment: .col-xs-4 {
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

In bootstrap, the grid summ need to be equal 12. Then if you want the xs to be a row, you need to change to `col-xs-4` because you only have 3 div.

Check more info here: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp

Answer (score 0):

If you want your layout to always be three columns use the xs breakpoint.  The different breakpoints are designed to change the layout based on screen size.